# How to get the tail of a std::string?

Tags: c++

How to retrieve the tail of a `std::string`?

If wishes could come true, it would work like that:

```
string tailString = sourceString.right(6);
```

But this seems to be too easy, and doesn't work...

Any nice solution available?

Optional question: How to do it with the Boost string algorithm library?

**ADDED:**

The method should be save even if the original string is smaller than 6 chars.

Comment: One question: do you want the last 6 characters or all but the first 6 characters ? It's unclear...

Comment: I want the last 6 chars.

Comment: One question remains after all the answers below: why on earth doesn't the string class have a member method `right(size_t)`. This would make life of a lot of C++ programmers easier.

Comment: What should it do if there are less than six character? Return the string as is? Return an empty string? Return the string padded to six characters?

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: not really. The truth is that the `string` class already has too many functions (duality index/iterator...). The Standard Library is not meant to provide for each data structure all the functions that could ever be useful (this would be insane), it provides core functionality that allows users to extend the behavior to catter to their own needs. Frankly: I've never had need of your precise requirement before :)

Comment: @Ferruccio: it should react in a defined behaviour of course. One of those you mentioned would be ok. It works in a lot of other languages, so why not in C++.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: So it boils down to what exactly is defined as the *core* behaviour of the string class. I would prefer a little more *core* functionality to enjoy an increased comfort, but I can understand your arguments.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: I agree, `core` is fuzzy. An objective line can be drawn when there is no (or little) performance loss obtained by adding the method as a free function in user-land rather than a built-in in the library. In general, a little syntactic sugar is provided on top of the `core` though, for example one could argue that `at` could be added easily as a free function :)

Comment: @matthieu: I've occasionally had this need. Some languages (including Python) have the feature that you can write `mystring[-6:]` or similar, with useful behavior on shorter strings, so it's not as if this is an exciting new innovation by Ronald. As you say, though, the answer is that `string` isn't a very good class. It has vast amounts of cruft and never the thing you want ;-)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There is one caveat to be aware of: if [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) is called with a position past the end of the array (superior to the size), then an `out_of_range` exception is thrown.

Therefore:

```
std::string tail(std::string const& source, size_t const length) {
  if (length >= source.size()) { return source; }
  return source.substr(source.size() - length);
} // tail
```

You can use it as:

```
std::string t = tail(source, 6);
```

Comment: +1 nice answer. Should be accepted answer IMHO. You could say this is elegant.

Comment: +1 nice answer to my question. It is *readable* code and exactly meets my requirements.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: Remember.. if this meets your intent, don't forget to check accept.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: Take it from me, this is better and testable.

Comment: You could also easily make it a template to operate on any `basic_string<T>`, or with a bit of faff to make it operate on any range with a bi-directional iterator and a constructor that takes `(iterator, iterator)`.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Yes I could. And I may if I needed it for something else :)

Comment: It looks like the code doesn't check that the position isn't superiour to the size of the string (as it's written at the beginning of the post). It checks that it's not negative.

Answer (score 17):

Using the `substr()` method and the `size()` of the string, simply get the last part of it:

```
string tail = source.substr(source.size() - 6);
```

For handling case of a string smaller than the tail size see [Benoit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597260/how-to-get-the-tail-of-a-stdstring/7597291#7597291) (and upvote it, I don't see why I get 7 upvotes while Benoit provides a more complete answer!)

Comment: Does this work with a string that is smaller than the required 6 chars?

Comment: @Charles: By default `substr` runs to the end of the string, so the second `6` is redundant.

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: No, it does not. An exception will be thrown.

Comment: no, Benoit's answer is better. If size is smaller, you'll get an memory access failure I think

Comment: @Ronald McBean - You just add a simple test to check the string length

Answer (score 11):

You could do:

```
std::string tailString = sourceString.substr((sourceString.length() >= 6 ? sourceString.length()-6 : 0), std::string::npos);
```

Note that `npos` is the default argument, and might be omitted. If your string has a size that 6 exceeds, then this routine will extract the whole string.

Comment: the first version does not handle the case you thought. Because `std::string::size_type` is most probably unsigned, `source.length()` will simply "wrap" around on underflow, and the result will be `std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max() - 6 + source.length()`, much greater than `0`. The second approach is right.

Comment: Wouldn't this be nicer: 'substr(min(sourceString.length()-6, 0) , std::string::npos)'? But it's a matter of taste I guess.

Comment: @Ronald McBean: No, because sourceString.length() is unsigned (`size_type`), therefore when you substract 6 you might have unexpected results..

Comment: @RonaldMcBean: using `min` on an unsigned type and `0`, the result is very predictable :p

Comment: @MatthieuM.But this code seems to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597260/how-to-get-the-tail-of-a-stdstring/7597802#7597802

Comment: A safer solution might be: `return std::string(source.end() - std::min(n, source.size()), source.end());`.  (But the original was also very good.)

Comment: @RonaldMcBean The solution, that you refer to, works, because it explicitely calls `std::max<int>`. It assumes, though, that converting from `sourceString.length()` to `int` doesn't cause over/underflow! So it is not really a good solution, either.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
string str("This is a test");
string sub = str.substr(std::max<int>(str.size()-6,0), str.size());
```

or even shorter, since subst has string end as default for second parameter:

```
string str("This is a test");
string sub = str.substr(std::max<int>(str.size()-6,0));
```

Comment: It won't work if the size is too big to be held in an `int` (I know, it's unlikely).

Answer (score 2):

You can use iterators to do this:

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string>
   using namespace std;

   int main () 
   {
        char *line = "short line for testing";
        // 1 - start iterator
        // 2 - end iterator
        string temp(line);

        if (temp.length() >= 8) { // probably want at least one or two chars
        // otherwise exception is thrown
            int cut_len = temp.length()-6;
            string cut (temp.begin()+cut_len,temp.end());
            cout << "cut  is: " << cut << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "Nothing to cut!" << endl;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Output:

```
cut  is: esting
```

Comment: This is returning the beginning of the string, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you also asked for a solution using the **boost** library:

```
#include "boost/algorithm/string/find.hpp"

std::string tail(std::string const& source, size_t const length) 
{
    boost::iterator_range<std::string::const_iterator> tailIt = boost::algorithm::find_tail(source, length);
    return std::string(tailIt.begin(), tailIt.end());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [substr](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/substr/) method.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

I think, using iterators is C++ way

Something like that:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

std::string tail(const std::string& str, size_t length){
    string s_tail;
    if(length < str.size()){
        std::reverse_copy(str.rbegin(), str.rbegin() + length, std::back_inserter(s_tail));
    }
    return s_tail;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::string s("mystring");
    std::string s_tail = tail(s, 6);
    cout << s_tail << endl;
    s_tail = tail(s, 10);
    cout << s_tail << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if source string is smaller than 6 chars?

Comment: Also, this looks awfully complicated.

Comment: @Ronald Of course, you should check length before. Edited to make the example more clear.
I don't think so, it's just a standard library usage.

Comment: @YuriS.Cherkasov: `substr` is much easier, and likely to be faster, because it'll involve copying a range in one swoop, while you copy character by character.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Not necessarily, if iterators point to a continuous range, the copying can be optimized.

Comment: @Erbureth: This is why I said *likely* I guess, though I would not swear on it. Whilst *in theory* the copy could be optimized I am afraid it will run afoul of the fact that the `back_inserter` calls `push_back` which is much more complicated than *just* copying, it also involves on-demand growth. Therefore, I would heartily applaud any optimizer which would succeed in transforming this reverse copy into a growable storage into a simple growth + `memcpy`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You're right, I've tested the std::copy and std::reverse_copy on std::string with gcc-4.8 and it looks like it doesn't optimize it to single memcpy call (not for short strings at least). It looks like some notion of ContiguousIterator \supset RandomAccessIterator is missing to cleanly implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
std::string tail(&source[(source.length() > 6) ? (source.length() - 6) : 0]);
```

Comment: You might want to explain a little bit what your code is doing, for completeness.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tail = source.substr(source.size() - min(6, source.size()));
```